# How to get better at English

Tags: american-english, learning-methods

I am not a newbie in English language, I can understand a lot but I can not speak   relatively good.  How can I get better,  how can I learn to speak/write more like a native speaker..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears to be a "How can I improve my English?" question, which is [off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Resources for learning English_](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english).

Comment: So how improve if you are not learning.  I would like to know (supposed that is off topic because is not about learning ).  If I am wrong please send me to terms and made me a recommendation so where can I check  what actually is off topic. Sorry for this but I am getting many of those when asking something and I really want to get better.

Comment: I gave you a link in the first comment. Here is is again. http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic Every SE is different, but you can find what is on topic if you click "help" at the top of the page and follow 'Help center' > 'What topics can I ask about here?'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an opportunity to live in an English-speaking country for a while, that would be the best way.

Otherwise, it's difficult to develop active ability in the language. The next best ways would be either to take an English class or to do grammar and/or translation exercises.

**Edit:** Immersion in a native environment is most effective if you seek out as many opportunities as possible for social and professional interaction with speakers of the language. Some people fall into the trap of travelling to a country to study its language but then failing to establish meaningful ties with native speakers.

Comment: Immersion is always the best way

Comment: @Peter Research  indicates that total immersion is not the best way. This is because students can get highly discouraged by the tremendous amount of the target language at use around them in ways that they do not understand.

Comment: @Clare Could you please specify what research you're referring to?

Comment: On the popular level, see for instance https://www.brainscape.com/blog/2014/11/think-study-abroad-will-make-you-fluent/  I could cite studies but I don't have that information with me.

Comment: @Clare Thanks for sharing that article. What it tells me is that some students on study abroad programs fail to take full advantage of the opportunity to have close contact with native speakers. It does seem plausible to me that at beginning or intermediate levels of proficiency, intensive study at home can be as effective as immersion for many students. That seems highly unlikely at advanced levels. I'd be interested to know what level the students were at in the study mentioned in the article. I'll edit my answer to reflect the content of the article.